# Rails: Dynamically create form fields, create multiple records with one submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

My website lets users book a car. There are many cars to choose from, cars have different `max_occupancy` numbers. Once the user selects a car the sign up process starts, the user has to submit a name for every passenger.

Models

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bookings
  has_many :passengers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
end

class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
end
```

Controllers

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  @car = @booking.cars.build
  @car.passengers.build
end

def signup
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @max_occupancy = @car.max_occupancy
  @booking = Booking.new    
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :cars do |car| %>
    <%= car.hidden_field :car_id, value: @car.id %>
    <%= car.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: 'form-control', min: 1     %>
    <%= car.fields_for :passengers do |passenger| %>
      <%= passenger.label :name %>
      <%= passenger.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Functionality
When the form first renders the default quantity is set to `1`, so on page load I would like the block

```
<%= passenger.label :name %>
<%= passenger.text_field :name %>
```

to render 1 * `@car.max_occupancy`. If quantity is increased or decreased, the block should get rendered n * `@car.max_occupancy` (where n is quantity as set in the number_field). Any blank `passenger` fields should be disregarded
How would I go about creating this functionality and how would I need to change the controller to create multiple `passengers` with a single submit.